# rdfs:label does not match in SPARQL. Divergence between the public interface and SPARQL dataset

Tags: sparql, rdf, openstreetmap

I am trying this query at [LinkedGeoData endpoint](http://linkedgeodata.org/sparql):

```
SELECT distinct * where {
?var rdfs:label "Arabian Courtyard Hotel & Spa".
?var geo:lat ?lat.
?var geo:long ?lon.
}
```

I know this object exists, but this query returns null. I can access the object with the URI: http://linkedgeodata.org/page/triplify/node315528887

The rdfs:label is an exact match, but the query returns an empty result set.

However, If I modify the query second line I can obtain the object:

```
SELECT distinct * where {
?var rdfs:label "Arabian Courtyard".
?var geo:lat ?lat.
?var geo:long ?lon.
}
```

Is this issue related to '&' character? Can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like there is a difference between the data shown via the pubby interface, i.e. when you open the HTTP URI in the browser and the data used in the SPARQL dataset, see [this query](http://linkedgeodata.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Flinkedgeodata.org&qtxt=%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+distinct+*+where+%7B%0D%0A%3Fvar+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fl+.%0D%0A%3Fvar+geo%3Alat+%3Flat.%0D%0A%3Fvar+geo%3Along+%3Flon.%0D%0Afilter+%28%3Fvar%3D%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flinkedgeodata.org%2Ftriplify%2Fnode315528887%3E%29%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: I'll ask the maintainer of LGD on this issue.

Comment: Thanks aksw! I will be grateful if you send me the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the source of the data:

1. The data in the [SPARQL endpoint](http://linkedgeodata.org/sparql) is based on an [RDF dump](http://downloads.linkedgeodata.org/releases/2015-11-02/) which is more than one year old.
2. The data that will be shown when you open the resource in the browser is provided by the SPARQL-SQL rewriter [Sparqlify](http://aksw.org/Projects/Sparqlify.html) based on an periodically synchronized SQL dump, thus, the data is up-to-date with the [OpenStreetMap SQL dataset](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data). This data can also be queried via SPARQL using either the [SPARQL service](http://linkedgeodata.org/vsparql) or the [Web Interface](http://linkedgeodata.org/vsnorql/).

Comment: Thanks, @AKSW. This is a very useful information! I am making a software to access OpenStreetMap dataset via SPARQL. I have sent many queries in sequence to <http://linkedgeodata.org/vsparql> and sometimes I get HttpException: 500. This exception occurs in different queries, so I assume this is not a syntax related problem. This exception did not occur with the [SPARQL endpoint](http://linkedgeodata.org/sparql)

Comment: I don't know the reason, but if those queries are similar then for sure it happens because you putting too much load on the service which in fact is a shared medium. What kind of queries do you send?

Comment: They are similar to the query I put in the question description. I have a variable instead of the literal "Arabian Courtyard Hotel & Spa" after the rdfs:label. The goal is retrieving a set of URIs to objects stored in OpenStreetMap. I agree with you, probably I am putting to much load on the service.

Comment: And nothing else is set? That means you're just extracting any data from LGD, probably by using pagination (`LIMIT n OFFSET n*i`), which indeed might be blocked after too many requests in a short time. If that's really the use-case you might think of loading the data into a local triple store in order to have full control over it.

Comment: I am a beginner in Sparql programming. I don'I know if I am using pagination. I am using Jena's [QueryExecution class](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/QueryExecution.html) to process the query. I believe I set only the timeout value. Do you know where I can download the updated RDF data? The newest I have found was from 2015.

Comment: SPARQL endpoint usually have a limit on the number of the results they deliver in a single request. This should be obvious, otherwise it would be possible to load the whole data with a single request, i.e. shipping GBs of data over the network. No public service would do this.

Comment: There is no newer version, that's so far the latest release.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for you help @AKSW